# Find 4 values in a list that are close together

Tags: python

I am trying to find the 4 closest value in a given list within a defined value for the difference. The list can be of any length and is sorted in increasing order. Below is what i have tried:

```
holdlist=[]
m=[]
nlist = []
t = 1
q = [2,3,5,6,7,8]
for i in range(len(q)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(q)):
        if abs(q[i]-q[j])<=1:
            holdlist.append(i)
            holdlist.append(j)
            t=t+1
            break
        else:
            if t != 4:
                holdlist=[]
                t=1
            elif t == 4:
                nlist = holdlist
                holdlist=[]
                t=1
nlist = list(dict.fromkeys(nlist))
for num in nlist:
    m.append(q[num])
```

The defined difference value here is 1. Where "q" is the list and i am trying to get the result in "m" to be [5,6,7,8]. but it turns out to be an empty list. 
This works only if the list "q" is [5,6,7,8,10,11]. My guess is after comparing the last value, the for loop ends and the result does not go into "holdlist".
Is there a more elegant way of writing the code?
Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that `t != 4` condition isn't what you want. Did you mean `t > 4`?

Comment: Ways that work are pretty elegant Why don't you like yours?

Comment: Have you thought about sorting the list?

Comment: @kojiro sorry i forgot to add the list is sorted. i have edited the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to sort the input list and find the smallest window of four elements. Given the example input, this is

```
min([sorted(q)[i:i+4] for i in range(len(q) - 3)],
    key=lambda w: w[3] - w[0])
```

But given a different input this will still return a value if the smallest window has a bigger spacing than 1. But I'd still use this solution, with a bit of error handling:

```
assert len(q) > 4
answer = min([sorted(q)[i:i+4] for i in range(len(q) - 3)], key=lambda w: w[3] - w[0])
assert answer[3] - answer[0] < 4
```

Written out and annotated:

```
sorted_q = sorted(q)
if len(q) < 4:
    raise RuntimeError("Need at least four members in the list!")

windows = [sorted_q[i:i+4] for i in range(len(q) - 3)]  # All the chunks of four elements
def size(window):
    """The size of the window."""
    return window[3] - window[0]
answer = min(windows, key=size)  # The smallest window, by size
if answer[3] - answer[0] > 3:
    return "No group of four elements has a maximum distance of 1"
return answer
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one easy approach to find four closest numbers in list

```
# Lets have a list of numbers. It have to be at least 4 numbers long
numbers = [10, 4, 9, 1,7,12,25,26,28,29,30,77,92]
numbers.sort() 
#now we have sorted list
delta = numbers[4]-numbers[0] # Lets see how close first four numbers in sorted list are from each others.
idx = 0 # Let's save our starting index
for i in range(len(numbers)-4):
    d = numbers[i+4]-numbers[i]
    if d < delta: 
        # if some sequence are closer together we save that value and index where they were found
        delta = d
        idx = i

if numbers[idx:idx+4] == 4:
    print ("closest numbers are {}".format(numbers[idx:idx+4]))
else:
    print ("Sequence with defined difference didn't found")
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this implementation takes the "defined value for the difference" constraint into account.

Comment: You are right, I missed it. And @kojiro wrote the same thing as a oneliner in another answer.

Comment: I rather suspect we're all going to discover sorting the list is illegal, somehow...

Comment: @kojiro That'd be a bummer. I guess we'll all have to wait for the OP to confirm the legality of sort.

Comment: @ex4 Thank you for your solution. Sorry i forgot to add that sorting is ok(i have edited my post). But this solution will be a problem if my list is less than 4 numbers long.

Comment: You are right. If your list  is shorter than four number you have to decide what to do. Raise an error (which this does) or return something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my jab at the issue for OP's reference, as @kojiro and @ex4 have already supplied answers that deserve credit.

```py
def find_neighbor(nums, dist, k=4):
    res = []
    nums.sort()
    for i in range(len(nums) - k):
        if nums[i + k - 1] - nums[i] <= dist * k:
            res.append(nums[i: i + k])
    return res
```

Here is the function in action:

```
>>> nums = [10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # slightly modified input for better demo
>>> find_neighbor(nums, 1)
[[5, 6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Assuming sorting is legal in tackling this problem, we first sort the input array. (I decided to sort in-place for marginal performance gain, but we can also use `sorted(nums)` as well.) Then, we essentially create a window of size `k` and check if the difference between the first and last element within that window are lesser or equal to `dist * k`. In the provided example, for instance, we would expect the difference between the two elements to be lesser or equal to `1 * 4 = 4`. If there exists such window, we append that subarray to `res`, which we return in the end.

If the goal is to find *a* window instead of all windows, we could simply return the subarray without appending it to `res`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a generic fashion (i.e. for any size of delta or resulting largest group) using the zip function:

```
def deltaGroups(aList,maxDiff):
    sList  = sorted(aList)
    diffs  = [ (b-a)<=maxDiff for a,b in zip(sList,sList[1:]) ]
    breaks = [ i for i,(d0,d1) in enumerate(zip(diffs,diffs[1:]),1) if d0!=d1 ]
    groups = [ sList[s:e+1] for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks+[len(sList)]) if diffs[s] ]
    return groups
```

Here's how it works:

- Sort the list in order to have each number next to the closest other numbers
- Identify positions where the next number is within the allowed distance (`diffs`)
- Get the index positions where compliance with the allowed distance changes (`breaks`) from eligible to non-eligible and from non-eligible to eligible
- This corresponds to start and end of segments of the sorted list that have consecutive eligible pairs.
- Extract subsets of the the sorted list based on the start/end positions of consecutive eligible differences (`groups`)
- The `deltaGroups` function returns a list of groups with at least 2 values that are within the distance constraints.  You can use it to find the largest group using the max() function.

output:

```
q = [10,11,5,6,7,8]
m = deltaGroups(q,1)
print(q)
print(m)
print(max(m,key=len))

# [10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# [[5, 6, 7, 8], [10, 11]]
# [5, 6, 7, 8]

q = [15,1,9,3,6,16,8]
m = deltaGroups(q,2)
print(q)
print(m)
print(max(m,key=len))

# [15, 1, 9, 3, 6, 16, 8]
# [[1, 3], [6, 8, 9], [15, 16]]
# [6, 8, 9]

m = deltaGroups(q,3)
print(m)
print(max(m,key=len))

# [[1, 3, 6, 8, 9], [15, 16]]
# [1, 3, 6, 8, 9]
```